# BootCamp Windows 7 partition shown as FAT32 instead of NTFS after update from Mac OS X 10.5(Leopard) to 10.7 (Lion)

Tags: windows-7, windows, osx-lion, boot-camp

I have a MacBook (Early 2008) with a 512 GB aftermarket Hard disk with about 450 GB allotted to Windows 7 and about 50 GB to Mac OS 10.5 (Leopard). I recently upgraded Mac OS from 10.5 to 10.6 (via CD) and from 10.6 to 10.7 via App Store. I have Windows 7 installed in a Bootcamp partition and is set as primary target disk to boot into Windows 7 primarily.

After I installed OS X 10.6, Windows 7 stopped showing up in the boot disks in the list at boot up (pressing Option button), but I was still able to set the Windows partition as the target disk in 'Startup Disk' application and reboot the computer to successfully log into Windows.

I then updated 10.6 to 10.7 via App Store purchase. After the install, my Windows 7 partition (NTFS originally) is showing up as FAT32 in 'Disk Utility' application and is Empty. I wanted to see if Windows Install CD repair options will help me, but was out of luck as the Install CD does not recognize that Windows is already installed on that partition.

Can I somehow mark that partition as NTFS? What is the best way to restore some data from that partition?